# CSS hover effect to modify another element is not working

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to get a `<p>` element to appear upon hovering over an image. As I have it, nothing happens when I hover over the image.  
 Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```css
img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #b6a9a9;
  background-color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 1em;
  opacity: .68;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1);
  height: 25px;
  width: 25%;
}

img:hover .stuff p {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="image.jpg">
<div class="stuff">
  <p>here's some text that will go on top of ths image ... I hope...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the text is to be already the over the image?or it needs to, besides scaling up, move it's position?

Comment: It's already over the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to add the `+` selector to the css definition

The `+` sign selector is used to select the elements that are placed immediately after the specified element but not inside.

So: `img:hover + .stuff p`, means: when hover over `img`, select it's "brother" with class `.stuff` and then select the `p` that is inside.

```css
img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #b6a9a9;
  background-color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 1em;
  opacity: .68;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1);
  height: 25px;
  width: 25%;
}

img:hover + .stuff p {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400">
<div class="stuff">
  <p>here's some text that will go on top of ths image ... I hope...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Calvin.  Unfortunately, when I add the "+" symbol, nothing changes.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: How nothing changes? Did you run my snippet above? Have you posted in your question ALL your CSS and HTML structure exactly as you are using in your development?

Comment: No idea.  However, I just re-ran the whole thing in a new window with a new image and it worked.  So, I suppose I have an answer.  Thanks so much Calvin!  I appreciate your help.